# How to use quick substitution to replace all the strings of the previous command?

Tags: bash, command-history

I know I can replace a string of the previous command using ^old^new. But it seems to only replace the first occurrences as I do the follow:

```
$ cat /proc/5742/task/5742/status
...
$ ^5742^2839
cat /proc/2839/task/5742/status
cat: /proc/2839/task/5742/status: No such file or director
```

How to replace all occurrences, if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `^old^new` corresponds to `!!:s/old/new`, you can use the following to make a global replacement:

```
!!:gs/5742/2839/
```